# How to update json in Data value type using Swift

Tags: json, swift

Imagine that I have following json in `Data` format

```
var data = Data("""
{
    "name": "Steve",
    "age": 30,
    "pets": [
        "dog"
    ]
}
""".utf8)
```

How can I change let's say first element of the `pets` to `"cat"` with keeping my `data` variable?

Answer (score 1):

First you need `struct` conforming to `Codable` matching to your json

```
struct Person: Codable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var pets: [String]
}
```

then you can use this generic method which takes object in `Data` type, decodes it and changes it how you declare later in `changeBlock` closure. Then it encodes it back

```
extension Data {
    mutating func update<T: Codable>(changeBlock: (inout T) -> Void) throws {
        var decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: self)
        changeBlock(&decoded)
        self = try JSONEncoder().encode(decoded)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
do {
    try data.update { (person: inout Person) -> Void in
        person.pets[0] = "cat"
    }
} catch { print(error) }

//print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
```

Comment: You managed to find an answer to your totally legitimate question really quickly

Comment: @mag_zbc yes, I posted this question because I hadn't found similar question on SO and I had thought that this could be helpful for some people.

Comment: It would be better if `update` was `Decoder`/`Encoder` independent. Even if it's just for `JSON*` there may be a need to use them with non-default settings.